# graphical LCD coding using c

Tags: c

I want to use a text size of 10pt on Graphical LCD, I searched for the 10pt on  net but I found only 10pt equals to 13px but I'm not able to understand what this 13px represents either width or height?
 If anyone knows how many pixels contains a 10pt sized font please let me know and also the conversion from pt to px(both width and height)

Comment: 10pt is exactly the size what you want it to be, depending on what DPI you want and the DPI of the LCD. Why do you want 10pt? If you don't even know what size it will be on that LCD? And just think: how could a size be the width, when letters like l and w have completely different widths.

Comment: That depends on the size of the pixel. One point is 1/72 inch, the height of the font.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen in embedded system programming especially when you program LCD you consider both height and width of the text.

Comment: @RaviS In any graphical programming you consider both. My comment still stands, characters are different widths so a constant cannot refer to the width, unless it's a monospace font.

Answer (score 2):

- a **point** is a physical distance, equal to 1/72 inch.
- a **pixel** is a picture element.

How many pixels are in one point depends on the resolution of your screen. Imagine you want to draw a 1cm line on your screen, then the number of pixels will depend on the resolution of your screen.

**13px** represents the height of the characters in your font, you can take a look at [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/4074)